# PHP read each file and search for string

Tags: php

I am trying to write some code to look through all of the files in my server and return files that contain a certain string.  The problem is that I only know the comment in the files I'm looking for is the key and I feel like this may be messing this up.

I have a function that recursively searches for files in all directories which works fine, but the reading of the file and searching of the string is not working properly.

```
<?php
$mal = "//###=CACHE START=###";


function getDirContents($dir) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file == "." || $file == "..") continue;
        if(!is_file($dir . $file)){
            echo "Folder: " . $dir . $file . "<br />";
            getDirContents($dir.$file."/");
        } else {
            echo "File: " . $dir . $file . "<br />";
            $content = file_get_contents($dir . $file);
            if (strpos($content, $mal) !== false) {
                echo "FOUND" . $dir.$file . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

$dir = "./";
getDirContents($dir);


?>
```

For some reason, this is returning .png and .jpg files as "FOUND" and I'm not sure why.  I have many files that have the `$mal` string in them, but it's a comment and I'm not sure if that matters.  Either way, it is not working properly and not finding the files that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails because the thing you're searching for is not actually in scope - in the function scope `$mal` is actually NULL and thus always found. This is outlined in the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
```

> This script will not produce any output because the echo statement
>   refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been
>   assigned a value within this scope. You may notice that this is a
>   little bit different from the C language in that global variables in C
>   are automatically available to functions unless specifically
>   overridden by a local definition. This can cause some problems in that
>   people may inadvertently change a global variable. In PHP global
>   variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going
>   to be used in that function.

A quick and dirty way to fix this is to declare `$mal` a `global`. Saner is to pass it in as a parameter to your function, along with the dir.

Comment: Ah, that was a bonehead move! I remembered that with the `$dir` but not the `$mal`.  Thank you.  That half-solved my problem.  Now, for some reason, I can't search for anything that is considered php code.  I have done some testing and was able to find `<div>` in many files, but what I need to search for now is the comment string which seems to not be working.

Comment: @ntgCleaner that seems like a different question. More generally, there's probably not much point re-implementing grep in PHP when you can just call grep.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find a block of code inside of multiple files so I may remove it.  My server was compromised and I have found the infection point, I just need to go through all files on my server and remove this block of code, which is written in php, not as a string.  Is there an option for this?

Comment: @ntgCleaner Yes. Wipe the server, install clean copy of code.

Comment: Haha, yes, that's my last resort.  I've found the affected files and the security hole, I have a list of affected files from the server and I'm just trying to make my job quicker by writing a script do delete this block, rather than me doing it the slow way. - I just wrote a new question to target this specifically.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Well. This is not really a topic for SO but the technical term for what you're attempting is some combination of 'ineffective' and 'batshit crazy'. Once compromised, you have no way of knowing the extent of the compromise. The attacker could have put backdoors in practically everywhere. "I say we take off and nuke the whole site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure". True for Xenomorphs, true for compromised servers.

Comment: You make some great points.  I have a struggle with this because I have a few clients who are using my space.  I feel like If I can fix it this time, if it happens again, I will, as you say, nuke it.  I do like starting fresh.

Comment: @ntgCleaner You really can't. You have a compromised server, and the machinations you're attempting will likely still leave you with a compromised server. Take this to ServerFault, there's probably an existing decent procedure there or someone can give you more detailed pointers. Think about the effort and time you're expending doing it the wrong way and consider that you basically are likely going to have to put that effort and time in again and again, likely with the same outcome.

Comment: ugh, I hate that you're right! haha.  Thank you for your help, I will start contacting clients..